# Searching for 1947 Italian immigrant to Venezuela?

Tags: 20th-century, italy, venezuela

I am searching for my late grandfather.  All I know is he imigrated to Venezuela around 1947. The family in Italy was told he died but there was never a death certificate issued.  His Name is LUIGI ROSCIO born 1913?.  He left a spouse and two children in Italy.  I have not been able to trace any record of his travels or death.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  How do you know that he emigrated to Venzuela?  And what is the basis for the date that you give for that?  Do you have birth/baptism/marriage records for Luigi?  I think your question would be more likely to attract potential answerers if you can [edit] it to provide more information about what you already know.

Comment: I know nothing.  My mother was 6 years old.  She rememembers going to the airport.  But I cannot trace anything in Italy.  She was told her died there but their was no death certificate issued.  I suspect that he didn't die and that he did a runner.  I have traced one Luigi to Brazil, but date of birth don't match.  I have tried to contact the the Fondi council, but to no avail.

Comment: Where was he born/baptised, and where did he marry/live in Italy before emigrating?  That information will be useful to try and establish his identity with any records found with the same or similar names.

Comment: unable to get any information.  I have emailed the council in fondi, Latina. to no avail.